# Zabbix and time series data from old-school devices

Tags: performance, monitoring, zabbix

We should monitor and log ~1000 devices (1..4 sensor per device). SMS and email alert and the common functions are required if anything going wrong.

I think we instead of developing the whole ecosystem in .NET/C# it would be nice to use an existing one - for example [Zabbix](http://www.zabbix.com/presentation.php). But is it possible without any bigger hack?

I think that the main problem is that the devices are old-school and using RS232 for communication.

Any idea or any other flexible monitoring software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well I run zabbix on multiple setups and it is pretty easy to setup [sms](http://www.zabbix.com/wiki/howto/config/alerts/smsapi) and email. As for RS232, it is not out of the box functionality that is provide by zabbix, nor do I think it will be. However it is possible, here is a [linux serial port script](http://ramblings.narrabilis.com/node/310) which has helped me in the past.

I recommend learning the zabbix [cookbook](http://www.zabbix.com/documentation/1.8/manual/cookbook), this will allow you to write custom scripts.